# Recreating the worst case in quick sort (1-10 permutation)

Tags: java, quicksort

I was asked to deploy a permutation of integers from 1 to 10 to recreate the worst case of the original quicksort algorithm (using the most right element as pivot). The only condition is to avoid the 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and the 10,9.....1 permutations.

How can i make this? What is the right tecnique?

Thanks.

Comment: Trying yourself is the right technique

Answer (score 0):

The right technique is to learn about the (quick-sort) algorithm, and read up on its worst-case performance, and when it occurs. Then you can easily construct an array of given integers on which the algorithm performs worst.

Comment: I understood the theory, but i can't undersdand how. If i try to recreate an empty array to the left or to the right, i'm able to obtain only 1.2.3.... and 10..9..8...1 permutation